# How do I start a ASP.NET Core Razor application from scratch

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get a clear mental picture on how an ASP.NET Core Razor application works. So I created an empty project template and tried to recreate the original "Razor Pages Template". After learning a lot of things the hard way, It seems just impossible to get a submit button to work. Take a look at some of my code:

**Create.cshtml**

```
<p>@Model.Message</p>
<h2>Create a new customer.</h2>

<p>Enter you name.</p>
<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
<form method="post">
    <div>Name: <input asp-for="Customer.Name" /> </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Create.cshtml.cs**

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    public AppDbContext DB { get; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public CreateModel(AppDbContext db)
    {
        DB = db;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }


    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = "This is from the get method";
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        Message = "This is from the post method";
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        DB.Customers.Add(Customer);
        DB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
}
```

Most of that code is from ([MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio)), It works if I create a Razor Template and then delete, and arrange everything to my taste. But when I create a project without the template, the button brings up a 404 error. Also, commands like `asp-validation-summary` are not made bold like they normally are when I'm using the razor pages template.

Comment: "Also, commands like asp-validation-summary are not made bold like they normally are ", you haven't finished then. That's from the `@addTagHelpers` line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Razor pages, you have to include a **@page** directive on the top of your page, otherwise it returns **404 Not Found**.

```
@page
@model CreateModel

<p>@Model.Message</p>
<h2>Create a new customer.</h2>
...
```

Comment: Hello Lukas, Sorry I didn't include those line in my question, but I actually have that in my code already. It still doesn't work. You should try to create a Razor application from scratch, you'll probably understand what I mean.

Comment: Ahh ok. It would be good to include your Startup.cs to check if RazorPages are correctly registered

Comment: That might actually come in handy. How do I properly register `RazorPages`? In the template there's a `services.AddMvc()` line but I actually added that too to my `Startup.cs` when I made my empty project.

Comment: Sorry, `services.AddMvc()` should already register razor pages. Btw. can you share your app as a github repo?